# Clean way of passing parameters

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public EmployeeProcessOutput  RetrieveEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput input)
{     
    var employee = input.Employee;

    if (input.EmployeeId == null)
        employee= CreateEmployee(employee);

    return new EmployeeProcessOutput
    {
        Employee = employee,
        State = "Stored" 
    };
}

private Employee CreateEmployee(employee)
{
    //Call a service to create an employee in the system using the employee info 
    //such as name, address etc and will generate an id and other employee info.
    var output = Service(employee)
    var employee = output.Employee;
    return employee;
}
```

Is there a clean way and of passing the `employee` parameter to the `CreateEmployee` method?  I feel that this line could be cleaner:

```
employee = CreateEmployee(employee);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What don't you like about it wizkid?

Comment: Next time, could you please make sure to include code that actually compiles?

Comment: Small note, possible failure point, you are checking if input.Employee == null but if input is null your app will crash, i'd suggest performing a if(input == null) throw new NullArgumentException("input") to assist in debugging later.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx). I think the real question is pass by value vs pass by reference.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708632/passing-objects-by-reference-or-value-in-c-sharp).

**Edit:**
The line could be modified to following:

```
CreateEmployee(ref employee);
```

and the method name would be:

```
private void CreateEmployee(ref employee)
```

Comment: Could you add anything from these links?  Link-only answers are discouraged here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with c#. But taking that its a OOP originated from c, I had given the answer.

Comment: objects are always passed by reference. "ref" is redundant here

Comment: @wizzardz I'm not familiar with c#, I thought `ref` may pass the parameter by reference. Thankx for a valuable comment :)

Comment: @wizzards No, it's not redundant. For reference types, the reference is passed by value, unless you use ref. And since the reference changes here, that ref is necessary.

Comment: @wizzardz: You are suffering from a common misconception which even some prominent Microsoft developers (those who participated in *Framework Design Guidelines*) suffer from. Svick is totally correct in pointing this out.

Comment: @svick: Thanks a lot for correcting myself, mate. That was a major misconception from my side

Comment: @svick, but it is redundant here. The new reference is returned by `CreateEmployee` method. I see absoultely no reason to pass parameter by `ref`, unless you are willing to add a quite confusing side effect to this method or make the method `void`. Not to mention, that since original code contains multiple compilation errors it is really hard to tell if the reference changes at all :)

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak You're right about that. I was assuming `CreateEmployee` would be changed to use `ref`, but also return `void`.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak Thankx for pointing that out. I almost forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is really confusing. Here is what i think what your signatures should look like:

```
public bool StoreEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    //here you set ID, etc. and store eployee into your system
    //the return value indicates whether operaration succeeded
    //alternatively you can return void and throw an exception in case of error
}

public Employee GetEmployee(string id)
{
    //here you fetch employee by id from your system
    //returns null or throws an exception if employee was not found
}


public Employee GetEmployee(EmployeeName name)
{
    //here you fetch employee by name from your system
    //where EmployeeName contains required info (first and last names?)
    //returns null or throws an exception if employee was not found
}
```

I am not sure where your input/output classes are coming from, but they feel really outdated. This is definetely NOT how you want to design a C# application. If you absolutely must return a state of operation - use method return value for that. And use `bool` or enums for that, not strings. But it is not something to build your application around when you are using an OOP language.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than finding a better way for calling method you need to re-factor your code. Depending on the situation you may create a new class which will provide you a fresh employee. But if this is a single task and need only once extract method can be a good solution. I've just extracted some code from your `RetriveEmployee` method into two methods.

```
public EmployeeProcessOutput RetrieveEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput input)
{
    return new EmployeeProcessOutput
               {
                   Employee = GetFreshEmployee(input),
                   State = "Stored" 
               };
}

private Employee GetFreshEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput imput)
{
    if (HasValidEmployee(input))
    {
        return input.Employee
    }
    else
    {
        return CreateEmployee(input.Employee)
    }
}

private bool HasValidEmployee(EmployeeProcessInput input)
{
    return input.EmployeeId != null;
}
```

Hopefully it is easier to understand then the original implementation. If you prefer ternary for single line conditional branching use it in `GetFreshEmployee` which will concise your code.